# KeyPairGenerator not found in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, cryptography, jce

When testing a Java class I've created using JUnit on Eclipse I get an error telling me: "the source attachment does not contain the source for the file KeyPairGenerator.java". I've just installed Java JDK and Java JCE Unlimited Strength Juristiction Policy Files. I use Ubuntu 11.04.
I get the same error for DSAKeyPairGenerator.java. Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like it's only a problem when you try to view the JavaDoc and/or Java source for those classes. Right?

Comment: Do you have BouncyCastle jars ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the [bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk16-146.jar) provider jar to java lib. Those classes are available in this jar.

Enjoy :)